# VideoView Crashes app. What's wrong?

Tags: android

Hi Guys This happens when I try to run my app, I am trying to stream a video using an url and this happens, app says "Application Failure detected" and crashes instantly. What's wrong?

```
05-07 20:48:41.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2678): in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.example.the
05-07 20:48:41.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2678): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-07 20:48:41.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2678): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.the/com.example.the.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.VideoView
05-07 20:48:41.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2678):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
05-07 20:48:41.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2678):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
05-07 20:48:41.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2678):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-07 20:48:41.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2678):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
05-07 20:48:41.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2678):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-07 20:48:41.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2678):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-07 20:48:41.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2678):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-07 20:48:41.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2678):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-07 20:48:41.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2678):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-07 20:48:41.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2678):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880)
05-07 20:48:41.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2678):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:638)
05-07 20:48:41.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2678):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-07 20:48:41.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2678): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.VideoView
05-07 20:48:41.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2678):     at com.example.the.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
05-07 20:48:41.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2678):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-07 20:48:41.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2678):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
05-07 20:48:41.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2678):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Since you did not post the source code, we can only guess, such as you are possibly calling `findViewById()`, which is returning a `VideoView`, but you are trying to cast it to be something else. Examine line 22 of `MainActivity.java` for more, as is indicated by your stack trace.

Comment: My source is: VideoView mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

  mVideoView.setVideoPath("http://the_url_to_the_video.mp4");


  mVideoView.setVideoQuality(MediaPlayer.VIDEOQUALITY_HIGH);

  mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));

Comment: Either `R.id.videoView1` is not a `VideoView`, or you need to clean your project (e.g., Project > Clean from Eclipse main menu) to fix up the incorrect resource ID.